# How to call a function(only known at runtime) with parameter values(only known at runtime)?

Tags: c++, call, std-function

At runtime a single test is made to determine which of two functions to call and also to establish parameter value(s).

The function is then called every few seconds.

```
void Foo::func( std::string s);
void Foo::func( std::string s1 std::string s2, std::string s2);
```

Obviously, its inefficient to test( which function to call ) for every call, especially when the function and its parameter value(s) will not change once established.

I need something like this:

Test once which function to call and established parameter value(s).

Assign initialised function to some kind of callable variable.

```
funcVar = void Foo::func( "blah", "blah", "woof" );
```

or

```
funcVar = void Foo::func( "blah" );
```

Then call function;

```
for( every few seconds )
{
call FuncVar;
}
```

Is there some kind of callable variable I can use to do this?

Comment: `std::function`?

Comment: You could work with function pointers that you set once in the beginning of your program

Comment: Can I set a function pointer to a function with initialised parameters? As for std::function, doesnt the number of args have to be known?

Comment: You could use std::bind?

Comment: I would have used an `enum` to store the test result (or `bool`ean) and use a `switch` / `if else` containing a `for`-loop with each their specific function - since all function overloads are known before run-time.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to store a function which can have two possible signatures? In that case you could just use two `std::function` objects and decide which one to use based on an `enum` or `bool`

Comment: If string arguments are known at the beginning you can bind them to std::function, and then call it later as function without arguments.
https://godbolt.org/z/Y3xPea

Comment: `std::variant` is also an option

Comment: Let's say the only input is `true` or `false`. Now, all you need to do is create an `if` test on it, so that if it succeeds, it will start looping over a function with preset variables. Else, it will loop over another function with preset varaibles. However, I didn't know `std::function` and `std::bind` existed, but they seem better (`C++`) solutions; mine was rather a general algorithm for any language.

Comment: I see that Klaus has visualized exactly what I meant. The only difference is that he doesn't duplicate the for-loop, by storing the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a lambda function object ( closure ) which you can call as often as you like.

Example:

```
struct Foo 
{
    void func( std::string s){ std::cout << "single" << s << std::endl; };
    void func( std::string s1, std::string s2, std::string s3) 
    {   
        std::cout << "tripple " << s1 << " " << s2 << " " << s3 << std::endl;
    }   

    // Select which function to call
    std::function<void()> Select( int what )
    {   
        if ( what == 1 )
        {   
            // Create a callable object and put in also parameters
            return [this]() { func("Hallo"); };
        }
        else
        {   
            // The same for the other selection
            return [this]() { func("This","is","tripple!"); };
        }
    }   
};  

int main()
{   
    Foo foo;
 
    // Pick what you want to select
    auto action = foo.Select( 2 );

    for ( ;; )
    {   
        // and call it as often you like
        action();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Was a close run thing thing between Klaus and Werner's answer, but the lambda syntax seems more simple and clear ..I learned something from all the various answers/comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::bind` for creating a functor with stored arguments and common call operator for both your use cases. Check this snippet:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
    static void a(std::string) {}
    static void b(std::string, std::string) {}
};

int main() {
    std::function<void()> x;

    if(true) {
        x = std::bind(&Foo::b, "a", "b");
    }

    x();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't overload functions of your object

Comment: The question asked is not about overloading functions, it is how to assign to variable different callables, and call it later without doing checks. So I've added answer to that question.

Comment: LearnMore mentions Foo:foo(std::string) and Foo:foo(std::string, std::string) and he wants to call one of the two overloaded functions.

Comment: Still, I believe it was rather a metasyntactic expression of askers' needs than a real piece of code, and the spirit of the question is about storing callables. If this answer will be not useful, other will be accepted, not a big deal.

Comment: The real code does involve overloaded functions, but Jakub's answer added to my understanding nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

If you want to std::bind overloaded functions, you have to specify which one you want to use:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>


struct Foo {
    void b() { std::cout << name << ": function 1" << std::endl; }
    void b(int i) {std::cout << name << ": function 2" << std::endl; }

    std::string name;
};


void with_map() {
    Foo f;
    f.name = "with_map";

    std::map<const int, std::function<void()>> map({
        {10, std::bind<void(Foo::*)(), Foo&>(&Foo::b, f)},
        {20, std::bind<void(Foo::*)(int), Foo&, int>(&Foo::b, f, 1)},
    });

    map[20]();
    map[10]();
}


void without_map() {
    Foo f;
    f.name = "without_map";

    std::function<void()> x = std::bind<void(Foo::*)(), Foo&>(&Foo::b, f);
    x();

    x = std::bind<void(Foo::*)(int), Foo&, int>(&Foo::b, f, 1);
    x();
}


int main() {

    without_map();

    with_map();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

std::function  should work here.

```
std:: function<void()> fun = [&s] () {/* do  work*/};
if (some_condition)
{
   fun = [&s1,&s2,&s3] () {/* do your work*/} ;
}

if(every few seconds)
{
    fun();
}
```